# Is おたくじじい a proper term to describe an old man who's into anime or is there another slang term for it?

Tags: slang, culture, anime, terminology, internet-slang

So as the question states, is おたくじじい a proper term to describe an old geezer otaku or is there a better alternative?

Comment: Cross-posted from Anime.SE: [What is the Japanese term for an old man/grandpa who is into anime/is otaku](https://anime.stackexchange.com/q/62519/2516)